# MS Access 2007: I cannot type in the text-box of a multi-select combobox control

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2007

If I setup a lookup for a field when designing a table (i.e. through the Lookup Wizard) and I set "Allow Multiple Values" to "Yes", a multi-select combobox (i.e. with check-boxes) is displayed in the relevant field in the "Datasheet" view of the table. My question is the following: Is the text-box component of a multi-select combobox control actually of any use? While a single-select combobox lets you type a new value that is not in the list or facilitates the auto-complete feature when typing a value that is included in the list, but the multi-select combo box prevents you from typing anything in its textbox, and that behavior doesn't seem to change via the properties of the combobox control.

The reason I need this feature is because I want to type there something not in the list, in order to trigger the control's NotInList event, so that I can update the corresponding lookup table with the new value I typed.

Thanks

Comment: _If I setup a lookup for a field when designing a table (e.g. through the Lookup Wizard)_ Unless you are using Sharepoint, this is likely to be a bad idea. See http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: I found the answer: You cannot in any way type the textbox component of a multiselect combobox and, thus, you cannot trigger the NotInList event of the control, as opposed to the single-select combobox case.